# Using sed to remove words with common prefix

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk

I'm trying to extract information from source code to create an API for others to use. I can grep the file to get a list of variables with common signatures, but some variables are polymorphic, so I can't clean them out as nicely.

For example:

```
public static Foo bar = new Foo(123, "Bar");
public static Foo baz = new Foo(222, "Baz");
public static FooBar fBar = new FooBar(135, "Foo", "Bar");
public static FooBaz fBaz = new FooBaz(256, "Baz", "Badger", "Baz");
```

I would like to simplify down to:

```
bar    123    Bar
baz    222    Baz
fBar   135    Bar
fBaz   256    Baz
```

Currently, I've done this so far:

```
grep "public static Foo" file.java |  tr '(' ' ' | tr ')' ' ' | sed "s/public\ static\ //g"
```

Which gives me this:

```
Foo bar = new Foo 123, "Bar" ;
Foo baz = new Foo 222, "Baz" ;
FooBar fBar = new FooBar 135, "Foo", "Bar" ;
FooBaz fBaz = new FooBaz 256, "Baz", "Badger", "Baz" ;
```

When I try to chain it with `sed "s/Foo*\ //g"`, it doesn't remove the words FooBar and FooBaz. How can I come about correcting this? Or is there a more elegant way to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: for the constructor, you just pick the first and the last parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with an awk on-liner:

```
awk -F'\\s*=[^(]*\\(|,\\s*"|"\\);' '{x=split($1,a," +"); print a[x], $2, $(NF-1)}' file
```

with your example:

```
kent$  cat file
public static Foo bar = new Foo(123, "Bar");
public static Foo baz = new Foo(222, "Baz");
public static FooBar fBar = new FooBar(135, "Foo", "Bar");
public static FooBaz fBaz = new FooBaz(256, "Baz", "Badger", "Baz");

kent$  awk -F'\\s*=[^(]*\\(|,\\s*"|"\\);' '{x=split($1,a," +"); print a[x], $2, $(NF-1)}' file
bar 123 Bar
baz 222 Baz
fBar 135 Bar
fBaz 256 Baz
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you are looking for

```
sed 's/Foo[A-Za-z]*//g'
```

In regex, `*` is a postfix operator, so `Foo*` matches `Fo` followed by zero or more additional repetitions of `o`.

To match "anything", you'd use `.*` but without additional constraints, that will match through the end of the string (dot `.` is a regex metacharacter which matches any one character except newline).

Comment: Right! How did this escape me! I actually know this pattern! :/  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following sed script does the entire job:

```
sed -ne '/^public static/s/.* \([^ ][^ ]*\) *= *new *[^ (]* *(\([0-9]*\),.*"\([^"]*\)"[^"]*$/\1 \2 \3/p'
```

Comment: Seems a bit complicated to me and doesn't seem to work against the example file :X Thanks anyways!

Comment: Sorry, there was one pair of `\( \)` too much. Corrected.